# Functionality of a start-stop-restart shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, console

I am a shell scripting newbie trying to understand some code, but there are some lines that are too complexe for me. The piece of code I'm talking about can be found here: https://gist.github.com/447191
It's purpose is to start, stop and restart a server. That's pretty standard stuff, so it's worth taking some time to understand it. I commented those lines where I am unsure about the meaning or that I completely don't understand, hoping that somone could give me some explanation.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #
    BASE=/tmp
    PID=$BASE/app.pid
    LOG=$BASE/app.log
    ERROR=$BASE/app-error.log

    PORT=11211
    LISTEN_IP='0.0.0.0'
    MEM_SIZE=4
    CMD='memcached'
# Does this mean, that the COMMAND variable can adopt different values, depending on
# what is entered as parameter? "memcached" is chosen by default, port, ip address and 
# memory size are options, but what is -v?
    COMMAND="$CMD -p $PORT -l $LISTEN_IP -m $MEM_SIZE -v"

    USR=user

    status() {
        echo
    echo "==== Status"

        if [ -f $PID ]
        then
    echo
    echo "Pid file: $( cat $PID ) [$PID]"
            echo
# ps -ef: Display uid, pid, parent pid, recent CPU usage, process start time, 
# controling tty, elapsed CPU usage, and the associated command of all other processes
# that are owned by other users.
# The rest of this line I don't understand, especially grep -v grep
    ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $( cat $PID )
        else
    echo
    echo "No Pid file"
        fi
    }

    start() {
        if [ -f $PID ]
        then
    echo
    echo "Already started. PID: [$( cat $PID )]"
        else
    echo "==== Start"
# Lock file that indicates that no 2nd instance should be started
            touch $PID
# COMMAND is called as background process and ignores SIGHUP signal, writes it's
# output to the LOG file. 
            if nohup $COMMAND >>$LOG 2>&1 &
# The pid of the last background is saved in the PID file
            then echo $! >$PID
                 echo "Done."
                 echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %X'): START" >>$LOG
            else echo "Error... "
                 /bin/rm $PID
            fi
    fi
    }
# I don't understand this function :-(    
    kill_cmd() {
        SIGNAL=""; MSG="Killing "
        while true
    do
    LIST=`ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $CMD | grep -w $USR | awk '{print $2}'`
            if [ "$LIST" ]
            then
    echo; echo "$MSG $LIST" ; echo
    echo $LIST | xargs kill $SIGNAL
# Why this sleep command?
                sleep 2
                SIGNAL="-9" ; MSG="Killing $SIGNAL"
                if [ -f $PID ]
                then
                    /bin/rm $PID
                fi
    else
    echo; echo "All killed..." ; echo
    break
    fi
    done
    }

    stop() {
        echo "==== Stop"

        if [ -f $PID ]
        then
    if kill $( cat $PID )
            then echo "Done."
                 echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %X'): STOP" >>$LOG
            fi
            /bin/rm $PID
            kill_cmd
        else
    echo "No pid file. Already stopped?"
        fi
    }

    case "$1" in
        'start')
                start
                ;;
        'stop')
                stop
                ;;
        'restart')
                stop ; echo "Sleeping..."; sleep 1 ;
                start
                ;;
        'status')
                status
                ;;
        *)
                echo
    echo "Usage: $0 { start | stop | restart | status }"
                echo
    exit 1
                ;;
    esac

    exit 0
```

Comment: Ah, `ps | grep -v grep`.  This is a common idiom.  That first `ps ...grep` (show "full" output for a single pid) is more efficiently written `ps -f $(cat $PID)`.  The `ps ... awk` (show pids for a certain user) is more efficiently written as `ps -u $USR -o pid=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)
`COMMAND="$CMD -p $PORT -l $LISTEN_IP -m $MEM_SIZE -v"` — `-v` in Unix tradition very often is a shortcut for `--verbose`. All those dollar signs are variable expansion (their text values are inserted into the string assigned to new variable COMMAND).

2) 
`ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $( cat $PID )` - it's a pipe: ps redirects its output to grep which outputs to another grep and the end result is printed to the standard output.
`grep -v grep` means "take all lines that *do not* contain 'grep'" (grep itself is a process, so you need to exclude it from output of `ps`). `$( $command )` is a way to run command and insert its standard output into this place of script (in this case: `cat $PID` will show contents of file with name $PID).

3) `kill_cmd`.
This function is an endless loop trying to kill the LIST of 'memcached' processes' PIDs. First, it tries to send TERM signal (politely asking each process in $LIST to quit, saving its work and shutting down correctly), gives them 2 seconds (`sleep 2`) to do their shutdown job and then tries to make sure that all processes are killed using signal KILL (`-9`), which slays the process immediately using OS facilities: if a process has not done its shutdown work in 2 seconds, it's considered hung). If slaying with `kill -9` was successful, it removes the PID file and quits the loop.

`ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $CMD | grep -w $USR | awk '{print $2}'` prints all PIDs of processes with name $CMD ('memcached') and user $USR ('user'). `-w` option of grep means 'the Whole word only' (this excludes situations where the sought name is a part of another process name, like 'fakememcached'). `awk` is a little interpreter most often used to take a word number N from every line of input (you can consider it a selector for a column of a text table). In this case, it prints every second word in `ps` output lines, that means every PID.

If you have any other questions, I'll add answers below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation of the pieces of code you do not understand:

1.

```
# Does this mean, that the COMMAND variable can adopt different values, depending on
# what is entered as parameter? "memcached" is chosen by default, port, ip address and 
# memory size are options, but what is -v?
    COMMAND="$CMD -p $PORT -l $LISTEN_IP -m $MEM_SIZE -v"
```

In the man, near -v:

```
$ man memcached
...
 -v     Be verbose during the event loop; print out errors and warnings.
...
```

2.

```
# ps -ef: Display uid, pid, parent pid, recent CPU usage, process start time, 
# controling tty, elapsed CPU usage, and the associated command of all other processes
# that are owned by other users.
# The rest of this line I don't understand, especially grep -v grep
ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $( cat $PID )
```

Print all processes details (`ps -ef`), exclude the line with grep (`grep -v grep`) (since you are running grep it will display itself in the process list) and filter by the text found in the file named $PID (`/tmp/app.pid`) (`grep $( cat $PID )`).

3.

```
# I don't understand this function :-(    
    kill_cmd() {
        SIGNAL=""; MSG="Killing "
        while true
    do
    ## create a list with all the pid numbers filtered by command (memcached) and user ($USR)
    LIST=`ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $CMD | grep -w $USR | awk '{print $2}'`
    ## if $LIST is not empty... proceed
            if [ "$LIST" ]
            then
    echo; echo "$MSG $LIST" ; echo
    ## kill all the processes in the $LIST (xargs will get the list from the pipe and put it at the end of the kill command; something like this < kill $SIGNAL $LIST > )
    echo $LIST | xargs kill $SIGNAL
# Why this sleep command?
## some processes might take one or two seconds to perish
                sleep 2
                SIGNAL="-9" ; MSG="Killing $SIGNAL"
                ## if the file $PID still exists, delete it
                if [ -f $PID ]
                then
                    /bin/rm $PID
                fi
    ## if list is empty
    else
    echo; echo "All killed..." ; echo
    ## get out of the while loop
    break
    fi
    done
    }
```

This function will kill all the processes related to `memcached` slowly and painfully (actually quite the opposite). 
Above are the explanations.